# python version 2.7.3 can't run /usr/bin/easy_install

Tags: python-2.7

I updated python from 2.6 to 2.7.3 in Mac OS 10.6.8. The version I checked in Terminal is 2.7.3. Then I installed easy_install using setup.py. There is no error in process of installing, but after installing, I cannot using easy_install. The error message is:

python version 2.7.3 can't run /usr/bin/easy_install. Try the alternative(s):

/usr/bin/easy_install_2.5 (use python 2.5)
/usr/bin/easy_install_2.6 (use python 2.6)

Run man python for more information about multiple version support im Mac OS X.

How can I configure to make easy_install work?

Comment: I think it's because the easy_install in your /usr/bin/ is an older version. I don't know how to update it. I have similar problem.